# Is $(-1/2)^n$ Cesaro summable?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cesaro-summable

It is easy if  $S_n=(-1)^n$; it is Cesaro summable to $0$.

But I am unable to find if the sequence $S_n=(-1/2)^n$ is Cesaro summable or not.

Comment: Fact: if $a_n \to a$, then $\frac{a_1+\dots+a_n}{n} \to a$.

Comment: In other terms, summable $\to$ Cesàro summable. Cesàro-summability would be of little use, if it were not an extension of usual summability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too hard to compute directly:

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^nS_k=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1/2)^k=\frac1n\cdot\frac{1-(-1/2)^{n+1}}{1-(-1/2)}=\frac1{3n}\left(2+\frac1{(-2)^n}\right)\to0$$

Comment: For an absolutely convergent series shouldn't the regular sum be equal to the Cesàro sum?

Comment: @MichaelMcGovern Yes, here $S_\infty=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(-1/2)^n=0$ is the regular sum. (agreed if you think this $S_n$ is confusing)